# average of dataframe rows based on condition

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, average, mean, conditional-formatting

```
data = {'a': [1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1],
                'b': [-2, 2, -2,2, -2, 2, 2,-2],
                'c': [-1, 1, -1,-1, -1, 1,-1,1],
                'Price': [138, 186, 124, 200,4, 6,5, 5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)
```

I have a huge dataset of 5000 rows like this. I would like to find the average of rows having (a,b,c), (-a,b,-c), (-a,-b,-c), (a,-b,c). Those are considered equivalent rows and I want the average price of them The output should be in this form: [image]

Comment: for each of the column a,b,c, divide it by its own absolute value (i.e. `df['a']/df['a'].abs()`), resulting in columns of 1 and -1 only. Then you can do `df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['Price'].mean()`

Comment: I think maybe I did not get your idea correctly. I have 5000 rows with different values of a,b,c. So if I divide each column by its absolue value and end up by columns of values 1 and -1, the grouping will not be accurate for example: 1 -2 3  and 6 -4 1 will both have 1 -1 1 form and will then be considered a group which is not what I need. I need only the 4 equivalents mentioned above to be grouped, so in this case the absolute value will not help. Did I get your idea correctly?